# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo- issue with facebook integration into personal app

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to integrate Facebook in my app. I want the user of my app to have the feature of sharing whats on his mind on his facebook wall.
attached here is my code along with the log file. I have declared everything in my manifest as well. I dont know why am i getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.integration/com.integration.FBSharing}: java.lang.NullPointerException

10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.integration/com.integration.FBSharing}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:286)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at com.integration.FBSharing.(FBSharing.java:34)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)

public class FBSharing extends Activity 
{

```
// Your Facebook APP ID
 String APP_ID = getString(R.string.APP_ID);

// Instance of Facebook Class
private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;

private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

// Buttons
Button btnFbLogin;
Button btnFbGetProfile;
Button btnPostToWall;
Button btnShowAccessTokens;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fblogin);

    btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fblogin);
    btnFbGetProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_get_profile);
    btnPostToWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_post_to_wall);
    btnShowAccessTokens = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_access_tokens);

    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

    /**
     * Login button Click event
     * */
    btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
            loginToFacebook();
        }
    });

    /**
     * Getting facebook Profile info
     * */
    btnFbGetProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            getProfileInformation();
        }
    });

    /**
     * Posting to Facebook Wall
     * */
    btnPostToWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            postToWall();
        }
    });

    /**
     * Showing Access Tokens
     * */
    btnShowAccessTokens.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            showAccessTokens();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Function to login into facebook
 * */
public void loginToFacebook() {

    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

        btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();

                        // Making Login button invisible
                        btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }

                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error

                    }

                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors

                    }

                });
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


/**
 * Get Profile information by making request to Facebook Graph API
 * */
public void getProfileInformation()
{
    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() 
    {
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) 
        {
            Log.d("Profile", response);
            String json = response;
            try 
            {
                // Facebook Profile JSON data
                JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                // getting name of the user
                final String name = profile.getString("name");

                // getting email of the user
                final String email = profile.getString("email");

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                {

                    public void run() 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });//end of runnable


            } //end of try
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }// end of onComplete

        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) 
        {
        }

        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) 
        {
        }

        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) 
        {
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) 
        {
        }
    });// end of request
}// end of getProfile

/**
 * Function to post to facebook wall
 * */
public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name","ICE App");
    params.putString("caption", "Bestbuy Deal for SONY Action Cam");
    params.putString("description", "Checkout SONY ICE For exciting deals!!");
    params.putString("link", "http://www.sony.com");
    params.putString("picture", "R.drawable.sony");

    facebook.dialog(this, "feed",params, new DialogListener() {

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Function to show Access Tokens
 * */
public void showAccessTokens() {
    String access_token = facebook.getAccessToken();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Access Token: " + access_token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

/**
 * Function to Logout user from Facebook
 * */
public void logoutFromFacebook() {
    mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
            if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // make Login button visible
                        btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        // making all remaining buttons invisible

                        btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }

                });

            }
        }

        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        }

        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You have a null pointer exception at line 34 of FBSharing.java.  What's there?

Answer (score 0):

If you read your stack trace, it says there is a null pointer exception at FBSharing.java:34

> 10-29 14:53:58.344: E/AndroidRuntime(6459): at com.integration.FBSharing.(FBSharing.java:34) 10-29

If I counted your lines of code correctly, this line is causing your app to crash:

`btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`

That means `btnFbLogin` is null.  Check the id of the button and make sure you are actually getting a reference to a button.

Comment: there are almost certainly imports at the top of this java file that he has not including in this posting

Comment: Hi Jesse, thanks for the reply. I have initialized btnFbLogin, and my xml contains button with an id btn_fblogin.. any hint?

Comment: Oh that is true, then it probably isn't the correct line that is causing the NPE.  You will have to find exactly what line 34 contains, and figure out the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to declare these in function `onCreate()`:

```
// Buttons
Button btnFbLogin;
Button btnFbGetProfile;
Button btnPostToWall;
Button btnShowAccessTokens;
```

I had the same problem. I fixed it liked this.

Comment: But they have been declared. Look at the 4 lines immediately following `setContentView()`.

Comment: Try declaring the buttons in onCreate().
    Button btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fblogin);
\\
    Button btnFbGetProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_get_profile);
\\
    Button  btnPostToWall =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_post_to_wall);
\\
    Button btnShowAccessTokens = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_access_tokens);

Comment: Are we reading the same code? OP *has* already declared the buttons in `onCreate()`, in exactly the same manner.